# Directory.GetFiles or DirectoryInfo.GetFiles returns empty list

Tags: c#

I've got some strange behavior during execution in a ASP.NET application.
It doesn't matter if I set workingFolder (see code below) to `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath` or any other public folder (current case).

I receive a ZIP file, unpack that file (using SharpZipLib) and try to digest the files in that folder, but the `System.IO GetFiles` returns an empty list.
I've tried to use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` and `Directory.GetFiles` : both an empty list.
If I breakpoint on the `Directory.Delete` and look at the folder I can see the files, they're not locked and I can do anything with the files - even if I set the "run from cursor" point at the beginning of the `foreach` no luck - the GetFiles still return an empty list (although I can *see* the files in explorer).

```
    private const string EXTENSION_LOG_FILE = ".txt";
    private const string VALID_EXTENSION_MASK = "*." + EXTENSION_LOG_FILE;

                var zipFolder = unpackZip(filePath, workingFolder);
            foreach (var zipFileInfo in new DirectoryInfo(zipFolder).GetFiles(VALID_EXTENSION_MASK, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                // never get's here
                value.AddRange(getLogItems(zipFileInfo.FullName));
                File.Delete(zipFileInfo.FullName);
            }
            // this fails: folder is not empty
            Directory.Delete(zipFolder);
```

and the unpackZip method:

```
private static string unpackZip(string zipFile, string workingFolder)
    {
        // doesn't matter what name I use, GUID or no GUID the GetFiles still returns an empty lists
        var tempFolder = Path.Combine(workingFolder, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()); 
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);

        using (var unzipStream = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(zipFile)))
        {
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = unzipStream.GetNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(entry.Name);
                if (fileName == string.Empty) continue;

                using (var streamWriter = File.Create(Path.Combine(tempFolder, Path.GetFileName(entry.Name))))
                {
                    var size = 2048;
                    var data = new byte[2048];
                    while (size > 0)
                    {
                        size = unzipStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tempFolder;
    }
```

any suggestions?

Comment: This `VALID_EXTENSION_MASK = "*." + EXTENSION_LOG_FILE` will lead to a double ".": `*..txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem which I guessed in
`private const string VALID_EXTENSION_MASK = "*." + EXTENSION_LOG_FILE;`
 retruns `*..txt` because `EXTENSION_LOG_FILE = ".txt"`